# Why postgresql query give different result as long as I run it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query

```sql
SELECT sum(t1.c1::float) AS total
FROM schema1.t1
WHERE ((1 = 1) AND (t1.c2 IS NOT NULL))
```

but every time I run it, it just giving me another result like

1. 174547685874384
2. 174547685874385
3. 174547685874386
4. 174547685874385

etc. and it just giving me unfix result.

Can y'all give me a way to handle it?

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: What is the datatype of column `c1`?

Comment: float, that's where you created the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the data type of `t1.c1`.

If the data type was declared as `real`, unexpected result may occur during mathematical calculations and data type conversions, because of the encoding mechanism of the `floating-point` data types.

I always use `fixed-point` data types (`numeric` and `decimal`), instead of `floating-point` data types (`real` and `double precision`).

Quick demo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    c0 numeric,  -- fixed-point
    c1 real  -- floating-point
);

INSERT INTO t1
VALUES (0.1745, 0.1745)

SELECT
    c0 * 10000000 ::numeric AS c0_cal,
    c1 * 10000000 ::float AS c1_cal
FROM t1
```

| c0_cal (numeric) | c1_cal (double precision) |
| --- | --- |
| 1745000.0000 | 1745000.034570694 |